# ajax logout (PHP) function

Tags: php, ajax

I'm new to ajax and am trying to make an onclick logout link. I am using php and need to destroy the session and delete the session cookie before continuing to the facebook logout url.

Can you take a quick look and see if I'm doing it right? It's not working but I'd like to make sure this part is coded right before bashing my brains in trying to figure out what the problem is.

Here's the link:

```
<a href="<?PHP echo $logout; ?>" onclick="logout()">(Log Out)</a>
```

In the head section of the html I have this:

```
<script>
function logout()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","logout.php?action=logout",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

And the logout.php file has this:

```
<?PHP
if ($_GET['action']=="logout"){
    unset( $_SESSION ) ;
    unset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ;
    unset( $_SESSION['fb'] ) ;
    unset( $_SESSION['temp'] ) ;
    unset( $_SESSION['access_token'] ) ;
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = null;

    delete_cookie();
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();

    if (isset( $_COOKIE[session_name()] )) {
        setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), time() -3600, "/" );
    }
    if (isset( $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] )) {
            setcookie('PHPSESSID', "", time() -3600, "/" );

    }
    if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
            $params = session_get_cookie_params();
            setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
                $params["path"], $params["domain"],
                $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]  );
    }
}

function delete_cookie($cookie = "pptoken") {
    setcookie($cookie, 0,  time()-3600, "/");
}


?>
```

Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: OMG, you are so paranoid by unsetting all session vars, setting to empty an then destroying it :))

Comment: Better to be paranoid in web development @KA_lin

Comment: its optional to be paranoid or not... why dont just answer the question?

Comment: You can use just session_destroy(); but you will need a js function to redirect the user on completion, in my opinion

Comment: But why not access logout.php and at the end redirect the user to the main page?

Comment: KA, because that causes problems with the FB logout. This has been pulling my hair, trying to find a way to logout without messing up the FB login. Destroying the session doesn't work after redirect messes it up and isn't recommended. (That's what I had originally).

Comment: Do I need to use the onreadystatechange? Or should it be fine the way it is? (since it's on a link)